# Ember.js Todos performance issue in Chrome

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I just started learning Ember.js. I've run through Getting Started section and Todos example that is shown overthere. While playing with code of that example I noticed that transitioning between child routes is very slow on my local machine in comparison to given example in live preview in JSBin (http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/show-all-todos-again/).

Then I noticed that the same performance issued arise when clicking on All/Active/Completed links when example is expanded to full window: http://jsbin.com/uYuGA/1 . So it's not a coding or dependency related issue.

In Firefox both embedded and full window versions run equally fast. Any ideas?

Comment: its running quickly for me. Disable any extensions you have installed in Chrome and try it again

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't seem to me that it is related since in the same Chrome in embedded window it works fine.